# Noob error: No route matches [POST] "/users/1/edit"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sooo... I'm a noob and I haven't found an answer that gets me through this yet.  I've been struggling through this and I know it's a simple question, but I'm just not experienced enough to know how to solve this one.

I'm receiving the error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/users/1/edit"
```

Here are the routes for the issue: (simple, I know)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :users
```

Here is the Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user=User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def delete
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @users=User.all.order("created_at ASC")
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :username, :admin, :email, :birthday)
    end

end
```

And, here is the view:

```
<DOCTYPE!! HTML>
<html>
<h1>Edit User</h1>
    <%= @user.username %>
    <%= link_to "Back to User Index", users_path %>
<%= form_for(:user, :url => {:action => 'edit'}) do |f| %>
    <table summary="Edit user form fields">
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:first_name) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:last_name) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:username) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Password</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:password) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Birthday</th>
            <td><%= f.date_field(:birthday) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Is Admin?</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:admin) %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<%= submit_tag("Update User") %>

<% end %>
</html>
```

I know this is probably not worth serious time for you to answer, but I haven't been able to figure it out.  Please help, and let me know if you need more info.  Thanks again in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<%= form_for(:user, :url => {:action => 'edit'}) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
```

In this instance, you don't need to specify the action to use. The default conventions in Rails will take care of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

As you already got an answer, so as a suggestion you can also add method parameter as given [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

```
<%= form_for @user, url: edit_user_path(@user), method: :get do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: I was able to try out both and they both worked, I made some connections as well, so thankm you!